# Using assets from node_modules for custom component Angular 2 Web Pack

Tags: angular, webpack

Recently I started working on Angular 2 and using WebPack for module bundler. I want to make my features independent so i created custom components and imported those components to the other components.

Portal
   -- node_modules (Feature A)
   -- node_modules (Feature B)
Feature A
Feature B

Everything works fine independently but when I publish the package for feature A and use it portal assets(images) are not working in Portal. I tried CopyWebpackPlugin but that needs a lot of tracking and anything can be messed when we manually configure in webpack.config file.

My question is can we just configure somewhere at Feature A in html or config files to looks for assets in their directory rather than looking for assets in portal?